# Categorizar un dataframe acorde con un criterio

Tags: r

Tengo varios dataframe como este:

```
            PV001_BWA
                      Pos           Depth        Region
                       942            32           3.aprotein
                       943            33           3.aprotein
                       944            32           3.aprotein
                       945            35           3.aprotein
                       946            30           3.aprotein
                       947            32           3.aprotein
                       948            32           3.aprotein
                       949            32           3.aprotein
                       950            30           CP
                       951            24           CP
                       952            20           CP
                       953            11           CP
                       954            19           CP
                       955            25           CP
```

Me gustaría saber como poder poder generar una columna más en el dataframe con la palabra "descartar" si no llega a 20 el valor de depth o "no descartar" si supera el valor de 20 en dicha columna.
De tal manera que genere algo así:

```
            PV001_BWA
                     Pos           Depth        Region             Tag
                      942            32           3.aprotein    Descartar
                      943            33           3.aprotein    Descartar
                      944            32           3.aprotein    Descartar
                      945            35           3.aprotein    Descartar
                      946            30           3.aprotein    Descartar
                      947            32           3.aprotein    Descartar
                      948            32           3.aprotein    Descartar
                      949            32           3.aprotein    Descartar
                      950            30           CP            Descartar
                      951            24           CP            Descartar
                      952            20           CP            Descartar
                      953            11           CP            Descartar
                      954            19           CP            Descartar
                      955            25           CP            Descartar
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para generar la nueva columna en la que cada celda tendrá uno de dos valores posibles en base a una condición, en este caso si el valor de `Depth` supera o no 20, puedes simplemente usar la función [`ifelse`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/ifelse):

```
PV001_BWA <- data.frame(
   Pos = c(942:955), 
   Depth = c(32,33,32,35,30,32,32,32,30,24,20,11,19,25),
   Region = c("3.aprotein","3.aprotein","3.aprotein","3.aprotein","3.aprotein",
              "3.aprotein","3.aprotein","CP","CP","CP","CP","CP","CP","CP"),
   stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

> ```
>    Pos Depth     Region
> 1  942    32 3.aprotein
> 2  943    33 3.aprotein
> 3  944    32 3.aprotein
> 4  945    35 3.aprotein
> 5  946    30 3.aprotein
> 6  947    32 3.aprotein
> 7  948    32 3.aprotein
> 8  949    32         CP
> 9  950    30         CP
> 10 951    24         CP
> 11 952    20         CP
> 12 953    11         CP
> 13 954    19         CP
> 14 955    25         CP
> ```

```
PV001_BWA$Tag <- ifelse(PV001_BWA$Depth >= 20, "No descartar", "Descartar")
```

> ```
>    Pos Depth     Region          Tag
> 1  942    32 3.aprotein No descartar
> 2  943    33 3.aprotein No descartar
> 3  944    32 3.aprotein No descartar
> 4  945    35 3.aprotein No descartar
> 5  946    30 3.aprotein No descartar
> 6  947    32 3.aprotein No descartar
> 7  948    32 3.aprotein No descartar
> 8  949    32         CP No descartar
> 9  950    30         CP No descartar
> 10 951    24         CP No descartar
> 11 952    20         CP No descartar
> 12 953    11         CP    Descartar
> 13 954    19         CP    Descartar
> 14 955    25         CP No descartar
> ```